# Collected passport from Tunisia as had applied for a UK visitor visa there was no visa in it and no refusal letter, who can I contact?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, visit

I have applied to visit the UK from Tunisia to visit family. I received an email to tell me a decision had been made and to collect my travel documents. I went to collect my passport back today and there was no visa issued and no refusal letter. Other people either had a visa or refusal letter. I was literally only given my passport. I asked the lady about it and she said they can't help they are given them like that.

Can anyone help me?
Who do I contact?

If I was actually refused, I want to know why so I can fix it.

Comment: Have you tried https://ukvi.mysecurepay.co.uk/Home?

Comment: No I hadn't thank you I couldn't find any information on who to contact. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

See [Contact UK Visas and Immigration from outside the UK](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y)

> An online enquiry costs £2.74 (GBP). This cost includes your initial email plus any follow-up emails you send relating to the same enquiry. You'll need a credit or debit card to use this service. You'll enter your payment details before sending your message, but you won't be charged until your message has been sent.

You should get an email reply within five working days. If your message is urgent, you can contact UKVI by phone Monday - Friday.